# How to specify which file to write to?

Tags: java, if-statement, java-io

I'm creating a program that takes the users input of currentSales, and if it's less than 1000 it goes to lowPerformer or more than 1000 goes to highPerformer.txt file. I'm stuck at the if statement. I'm not sure how I would code the program to tell the data what file to save to. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
public class HighandLowSales {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
      Path highPerformer =
              Paths.get("C:\\Users\\C\\Desktop\\IS103 "
                      + "Programming Logic\\Week7\\HighSales.txt");
      Path lowPerformer = 
              Paths.get("C:\\Users\\C\\Desktop\\IS103 Programming Logic\\"
                      + "Week7\\LowSales.txt");
      String delimiter = ",";
      String s;
      int id;
      String firstName;
      String lastName;

      double currentSales;
      final int QUIT = 999;
      try {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         OutputStream output = 
            new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(highPerformer, CREATE));
         OutputStream output1 =
            new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(lowPerformer, CREATE));

         BufferedWriter writer = 
            new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));
         BufferedWriter writer1 = 
            new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output1));

         System.out.print("Enter employee ID number >> ");
         id = input.nextInt();
         while(id != QUIT) {
            System.out.print("Enter first name for employee #" + 
                             id + " >> ");
            input.nextLine();
            firstName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter last name for employee # " +
                             id + " >> ");
            input.nextLine();
            lastName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter current month sales in whole dollar " +
                             "for employee #" + id + " >> ");
            input.nextLine();
            currentSales = input.nextDouble();
            s = id + delimiter + firstName + delimiter + lastName + delimiter
                            + currentSales;

            if (currentSales>1000) 
               writer.write(s);


            writer.newLine();
            writer1.newLine();
            System.out.print("Enter next ID number or " + QUIT +
                             "to quit");
            id = input.nextInt();
         }
         writer.close();

      } catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Message: " + e);
      }          
   }          
}
```

Comment: You add a new line to writer every time, but to writer1 never. You should add braces around all your ifs and elses and then see if it works.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer I have made the updates, but it is not working.

Comment: did I see that right, you accepted an answer as "correct", included the answerers code into your question and then try it? That will not work well :) Please leave the original code in there (except formatting, please fix that before posting code again anywhere). Or else the answerers you get are no longer valid which makes them bad out of no fault of their own.

Comment: You should look into "try-with-resources", that way you can skip the close statements.

Comment: Try adding "writer.flush(); writer1.flush();" directly before the close statements. (also add writer1.close();)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(currentSales>1000){
    //write to high performer file
    writer.write(s);
} else {
    //write to low performer file
    writer1.write(s);
}
```

Comment: where you put the comment //write to high performer file that's the code I'm not really understanding. What would I write there.

Comment: that's where you put the code for writing to a file... in your case writer.write(s); for high performer and writer1.write(s); for low performer

Comment: thanks. Not sure if you know this. Any idea why a path can't be converted to boolean?

Comment: well boolean is a true|false value... that's a single bit of information and path can't fit into a boolean value... you can probably make a method that returns a boolean value based on some state of the path that you want to do tests on.